# calling a function from another page in button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to call scroll function in another page..The content for scrolling is in another page and the button for scrolling is in headerpage..

```
scrollMore() {
  scroll.scrollMore(100);
}
```

This is the scroll function i used which is written in content page

```
<button title="Scroll" onClick={this.scrollMore} className="dashboard-patients-header_scroll">
  <ScrollIcon/>
</button>
```

This is the button which call this function which is written in header page.. But the function doesn't work properly.. What all changes need?

Answer (score 0):

You can export it:

```
# headerpage
export const scrollMore = () => {
  scoll.scollMore(100);
}
```

and import it on the other side:

```
# other page
import {scollMore} from './headerpage';
...
<button title ="Scroll" onClick={scrollMore()} className ="dashboard-patients-header_scroll">
  <ScrollIcon/>
</button>
```

or you can use properties:

```
class Headerpage extends Component {

    scrollMore() {
        scoll.scrollMore(100);
    }

    render() {
        return <OtherPage scollMore={this.scrollMore} />
    }

}

class OtherPage extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <button title="Scroll" onClick={this.props.scrollMore} className="dashboard-patients-header_scroll">
                <ScrollIcon />
            </button>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: scrollMore is doesn't works..It shows undefined.. why?

Comment: which of the three did you try?